# tar specific number of file

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a directory with 27K files, I would like to tar them into multiple **INDEPENDENT** tar files, each will have 5000 files and the last one, will obviously have 2K (27K is not dividable by 5).

What is the fastest/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First create files with the filenames for each archive:

```
find <directory> | split -l 5000 - files.
```

Then create the tars:

```
for f in files.*; do tar -cf $f.tar --files-from $f; done
```

Untested but the basic idea should work.

Comment: This is probably the quickest (in terms of typing) / most portable (should work on any unix - `find`, `split` and `for` loops in Bourne shells are everywhere) solution :)

Comment: Use "find <directory> -type f" so that the pathnames passed into tar don't include directories.  Alternative: for small split sizes, you could could use xargs insteads of split and avoid all the temp files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
files=( dir/* )

n=1
for ((i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; i+=5000)); do 
  IFS=$'\n' tar cvzf foo_$((n++)).tgz --files-from - <<<"${files[*]:i:5000}"
done
```

#### Explanation

Create an array called `files` that contains all contents of directory `dir`.  Iterate over the array increasing the iterator 5000 at a time.  Use the **offset parameter expansion** on the array to do a sliding window of up to 5000 items at a time `"${files[@]:i:5000}"` and pass that to `tar` and increment the file name by one `$((n++))` on each call.

Comment: Bash might throw an "argument list too long" at you if you do this. It's possible to pipe the filenames to tar if you use `--files-from -`. That might work better here.

Comment: @RobWouters Great idea. Did it in a slightly different way but this shouldn't cause any max arg errors.

Comment: Aren't you passing all those arguments to `printf` now though? Same problem.

Comment: @RobWouters doh, you're right! Ok, 3rd time's the charm